# Argument of type 'xyz[ ] | null ' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Collection<unknown>'

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

I'm writing a scenario where I get all the blogposts related to a certain category and I'm handling them using pagination by using `ngx-Pagination`. But when I reload the browser the posts does not remain on the page and all the posts are lost. And to cover that I'm using somekind of Of `Observable Subscription` methode by catching url route. With that methode I'm able to store posts even if the page is reloaded. But the issue is that now I'm not able to use pagination as I have to use `async` in my for loop to dynamic subscribe and destroy. And I'm facing the error when I try to use both `async` and `pagination` in for loop.

> - error TS2345: Argument of type 'PostSchema[] | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Collection'.
>
> 10                 | async
> ~~~~~

**ngFor loop where I'm trying to use both `| async` and `| paginae:{}`, and getting error on `| async`**

```
*ngFor="let post of blogposts$ | async | paginate
        : {
            id: 'paginate',
            itemsPerPage: 4,
            currentPage: page,
            totalItems: result.length
          }"
```

**ts file where I'm using some method to maintain the posts**

```
 page: number = 1;

  blogposts$: Observable<PostSchema[]> = this.activeroute.params.pipe(
    switchMap((param: Params) => {
      const postCategory: string = param['category'];
      return this.postService
        .getCategoryPosts(postCategory)
        .pipe(map((blogEntery: PostSchema[]) => blogEntery));
    })
  );
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
```

**service.ts code**

```
url: string = 'http://localhost:3000';

  public getCategoryPosts(category: string): Observable<PostSchema[]> {
    return this.http.get<PostSchema[]>(
      `${this.url}/blog-post/categoryPosts/${category}`,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    );
  }
```

**If I don't use the Subscription method I lose the posts over reload, and If use it I'm not able to use pagination. I tried by using `OnDestroy` but I couldn't find `unsubscribe` in that. A solution is needed as I want both results**

Comment: could you share component code

Comment: I've added some code please check if that's you are asking

Comment: why you don't set your blogspots$ variable in ngOnInit function.

Comment: I've solved the issue even I'm writing in the answer box right now. I ask you to stay and see the answer if that could be improved

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz
Even If I use the code in `ngOnInit`, I still have to provide type `any` to solve the issue. `blogposts$!: Observable<PostSchema[] | any>;`

Answer (score 0):

**I've made the solution**
The error was due to `types` of `Observable[Array]` and `Pagination`.
So I also focused on handling types instead of handling `ngFor`.I tried with `unknown` and `Collection<unknown>`, but with the help of type `any` the issue is solved.
**Old ts code**

```
blogposts$: Observable<PostSchema[]> = this.activeroute.params.pipe(
    switchMap((param: Params) => {
      const postCategory: string = param['category'];
      return this.postService
        .getCategoryPosts(postCategory)
        .pipe(map((blogEntery: PostSchema[]) => blogEntery));
    })
  );
```

**Current Solution**

```
 blogposts$: Observable<PostSchema[] | any> = this.activeroute.params.pipe(
    switchMap((param: Params) => {
      const postCategory: string = param['category'];
      return this.postService
        .getCategoryPosts(postCategory)
        .pipe(map((blogEntery: PostSchema[]) => blogEntery));
    })
  );
```

**Currrent working NgFor Also as the `totalItems` property will make issue as well with new settings**

```
  *ngFor="
              let post of blogposts$ | async | paginate : {
                id: 'paginate',
                itemsPerPage: 4,
                currentPage: page,
                totalItems: (blogposts$ | async)?.length || 0
              }
                  
            "
```